# Change cell type of excel cells using Apache Poi 5.1

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to change the cell type from general to numeric of an excel sheet using Apache Poi. I have made the .xlsx file on my own from a `.csv` file using Poi itself. Now I need to change the cell_type of "E" and "F" column of the xlsx file to numeric. This is what I've tried:

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(final_report_name);
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet new_sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        
        XSSFDataFormat format = workBook.createDataFormat();
        XSSFCellStyle style = workBook.createCellStyle();
        style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#"));
        
        new_sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(4, style); //These don't work
        new_sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(5, style);  //They keep the cell type general
        
        XSSFRow row = new_sheet.getRow(3);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(5);  //This changed the cell type to "#"
        cell.setCellStyle(style);   // But the number is still displayed as text

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream(final_report_name);
        workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
        workBook.close();
```

The column styling does not work at all, and the cell styling worked, but the number is still displayed as text. I still need to manually go to the hovering icon next to it which says "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe". then I need to click on "Convert to number" menu (see image). What could be the problem here and how do I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Setting the cell style does not automatically change the cell type. The cell type depends on the cell content. Not even explicitly setting the cell type using [Cell.setCellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType-) will always automatically change the cell type if content don't match that type. So you need setting the cell content aka cell value correct.

There are various `setCellValue` methods in [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html). If `setCellValue(java.lang.String value)` or `setCellValue(RichTextString value)` is used, the cell type will always be text. Do using `setCellValue(double value)` for numeric values, `setCellValue(boolean value)` for boolean values (TRUE or FALSE) and one of the various `setCellValue(DATETYPE)` (`setCellValue(java.util.Calendar value)`, `setCellValue(java.time.LocalDateTime value)`, ...) for date values.